# Holding unique pairs of enums and associating values to them

Tags: java, oop, types, enums, data-modeling

I have 2 enums, and a combination of each enum value with each other enum value exists. So for example with my 2 enums of 5 possible values each, that is 25 possible combinations. I want a way for an object instance of a class to "have" a value for each combination.

I am a little bit stumped on how to do it. I think it's a class design problem and I'm forgetting something obvious. So far what I thought of is to use a Map in Java that holds basically a pair.. The class has a value for an enum A and a value for an enum B, and its equality comparison compares whether the value for both enums are the same.
So (in code):

```
class EnumPair {
    EnumA a;
    EnumB b;
}

// with equals() implemented
```

Then I use a map that holds the pair class as a key and then a value as a value for the key.. This allows me to associate value payloads to the pairs. But I'm not sure if what I'm doing is correct? What I have is:

```
    class EnumPair {
        EnumA a;
        EnumB b;
    }
    
    class ValueHolder {
        int someInt;
        String someText;
    }

Map<EnumPair, ValueHolder> = new HashMap<>();
```

Is the map the right way to go about it? Because there are also a limited amount of combinations possible for the EnumPair since it is a combination of one enum and another enum. Because enums have finite definitions, there are a limited amount of combinations possible. In this instance it would be 25 combinations. This would mean that it's sort of a waste to generate up to 25 objects containing a pair of enums per map for the pairs when technically only 25 possible combinations exist, and only the values differ per instance of a map holding these combinations.

I don't know how I would model this without the map though. I think the map might be in the right direction, but where could limited existing pairs live in the code? I feel like I am missing some key piece of theory or forgetting some way to design classes or data types, because I am puzzled on how to do this. I feel like generics might be in the realm of the solution but I just can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: Nah, you've got the right idea.  Don't overoptimize by trying to avoid allocating the pairs as objects.  The one alternative might be to use an `EnumMap<EnumA, EnumMap<EnumB, ValueHolder>>`.

Comment: How about making `PairWithValue` an enum? And you could validate the pairings in a static block if you want.

Comment: @shmosel, how does that make sense with the "arbitrary int and string" values?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I'm not sure what you're quoting. I assumed they're constant values. But the question is not very clear. Some sample code would definitely help.

Comment: @shmosel I updated the question, I think I overexplained some things and was confusing in other bits about what I was actually asking.